# uninitialized constant OrdersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uninitialized-constant

I have a **Order controller** and a **Order model**like this ;-

```
class OrderController < ApplicationController

def new
    @cart=current_cart
    if @cart.items.empty?
        flash[:error]="Your cart is empty"
        redirect_to :back
        return
    end

    @order=Order.new

end

def create
    @order=Order.new
end

end
```

My **routes.rb** has

```
get "order/new"
resources :orders
```

And a form in **new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order, html: {class: 'form-horizontal control-group '}) do |f| %>   
<%= f.button :submit, "Place Order", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I do also have other fields in the form.

But when I submit the form it throws the error

> uninitialized constant OrdersController

What's wrong?

Comment: but why do I need that? i had created the controller with the **rails g controller order** method

Comment: then the new action won't render. it gives **undefined method `orders_path'** at the simple_form_for thing.

Comment: I think its better to stick to the rails convention and instead of fixing here and there generate a new controller using `rails g controller orders`, so that you don't have to change your code in many different places.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your controller name is `OrderController` (*singular*) and the error is complaining it cannot find `OrdersController` (*plural*). You also specified `resources :orders` in your routes (*plural*) which must match the controller name.

Rename your controller to `OrdersController`; this follows the Rails convention of plural controller names.